# Are expdp/impdp commands appropriate for daily schema sync?

Tags: oracle, import, data-synchronization, impdp, expdp

I've done following comands:

```
expdp system/password@localdb ^
schemas=SCH directory=dumps_dir dumpfile=SCH_%date%.dmp logfile=expdpSCH_%date%.log
```

It runs great, without errors. But when I use command:

```
impdp system/password@localdb ^
schemas=SCH directory=dumps_dir dumpfile=SCH_%date%.dmp logfile=impdpSCH_%date%.log
```

It gave me bunch of errors that tables, sequences and other stuff already exist. So I have a question, could I use such an approach or it's wrong and I should use something else?

Comment: what you are getting error? Can you share for better understanding. In which oracle version you are using in your environment.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan I just want to know is it right way to sync with this commands. I have two identical databases and I want to sync them. Errors - is common errors when you try to think schema that had been created. But is this a tool I should use?

Comment: I do not see why you cannot use it. You have to take the inconveniences. You can also create a script to generate a script to disable all these constraints and on to enable them again after the import. Constraints are often a problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for more information or type `impdp help=y`. There is a parameter (*TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION*) that defines if you want to overwrite existing objects or if you want to append.

> TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION
>   Action to take if imported object already exists.
>   Valid keywords are: APPEND, REPLACE, [SKIP] and TRUNCATE.

Comment: Just be aware that the REPLACE and TRUNCATE options may fail if there are any referential constraints on the table.

Comment: I have some sequenced. How to deal with it? I think I could remove schema and reimport it, but I feel like using wrong tools.

Comment: Removing the schema certainly works and `impdp` should create the schema before it does the import of the data. I never used the `impdp` to synchronise. You can also drop the sequences but first try to see if it the parameter solves the problem with the sequences too. Also instead of importing from a file you can also import through a database link in the destination database towards the source. Just use the `NETWORK_LINK` parameter to define this link.

Comment: I can't use network link, because of long data. So if it is ok to use impdp for such synchronization, then I'll use it.

Comment: Other way is transportable tablespace if the whole schema is in a separate tablespace but I cannot help/advise you on that.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not a possible way:

- Most of the non-table objects will already exist in your schema. You already get such error messages. The import will not overwrite it.
- You can configure how export should work if a table already exists but if there is a table that s referenced by another table then TRUNCATE and REPLACE will not  work.
- Even if there is no foreign key reference to a table indexes will slow down the import dramatically
- A lot of other problems may occur (concerning triggers, partitions, references to other tables and maybe more)

So the only reasonable way to synchronize the schema using expdp/impdp is to drop the schema before you import.

If you don't want to drop the schema for some reason but replace the data of the tables  a lot of additional operations are necessary.